# Identity column as part of primary key

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose, I have a composite primary key that consists of 3 columns: [ShardKey], [SiteId] and [ServiceId].
Column [ServiceId] is an identity column and should start from 1 for a new combination of [ShardKey] and [SiteId], but SQL server fails - the column [ServiceId] never starts from 1, it just increments its value no matter what the primary key is. I did add constraint for primary key that holds all three columns. 
What should I do to make it start from 1 when a new combination of [ShardKey] and [SiteId] comes in?

```
[ShardKey] [SiteId] [ServiceId]   [Name]
  1009        1         1         Coffee
  1009        1         2         Tea
  1009        1         3         Cocaine

  1009        2         1         Coffee
  1009        2         2         Tea
  1009        2         3         Cocaine

  1010        1         1         Coffee
  1010        1         2         Tea
  1010        1         3         Cocaine
```

That's what I want SQL server to do for me. Values for [ShardKey] and [SiteId] are known to me, so I can always insert them into SQL script, but I need the column [ServiceId] to start from 1 for a new combination of [ShardKey] and [SiteId]

Comment: That isn't what an `IDENTITY` does. an `IDENTITY` increments **every** time an `INSERT` is *attempted*. It doesn't care about the values of the other columns.

Comment: Sounds like what you want is multiple `SEQUENCE` objects (one for each combination of `ShardKey` and `SiteId`?) and then use the appropriate `SEQUENCE`. Of course, if you have a lot of different values for `ShardKey` and `SiteId`, that isn't a maintainable solution.

Comment: When a new combination of [ShardKey] and [SiteId] is encountered, it should increment [ServiceId] column. Columns [ShardKey] and [SiteId] are not identity columns, they have a known value, but the [ServiceId]. I need it for upsert operations and it should automatically increment in context of combination: [ShardKey] and [SiteId]

Comment: OK, I will add example in the major post

Comment: as a side note: you may also want to think about physical page shuffling; a composite primary key like this might be a good candidate for leaving the primary key *nonclustered* (so inserts don't cause shuffle), with it either remaining a heap (no clustered index), or using some other clustered index *where that makes sense* (for example: `CreationDate` might be a good candidate for a clustered index here); conversely; it might be that you're happy to pay the insert/shuffle cost of clustering on the PK, in order to get the benefits of reduced page fetches when fetching all for shard/shard+site

Comment: @NickReshetinsky What's the point of the `[ServiceId]`? Why not calculating it in the presentation layer? It can easily calculated using ROW_NUMBER function on read. So, could you share more details on the usage of the column?

Comment: @gotqn until somebody deletes a row... or you're using a predicate to filter rows to (say) "all open records", or two rows get inserted basically at the same time (so there's no obvious unambiguous "order by" mechanism to guarantee the row-number)

Comment: @MarcGravell I can't get how you are answering a question (like this) or commenting for issues before knowing the details. It's better to understand clear what the OP needs before leaving broad answers demonstrating how many tech words you know.

Comment: @gotqn what Nick is trying to do here is perfectly clear from the question, certainly plenty enough to get to the key points. It isn't about "demonstrating how many tech words [I] know" - it is about understanding the scenario and cutting through to the key points. If you think there is something unclear or irrelevant in my answer, feel free to comment on the answer or add something constructive of your own by way of an answer. But: the answer I gave was in no way "broad". It was very specific to a very clear scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no, `IDENTITY` can't help you here" - `IDENTITY` is per-table, not per-unique-other-primary-key-components. So: you'd have to handle this yourself (presumably checking the maximum `ServiceId` for that permutation), but then you get into complex race condition scenarios. It also makes insert very complex and less efficient, as now you're doing a `select` immediately before the `insert` - a prime candidate for deadlocking in some isolation levels (so: that initial `select` would need to be `UPDLOCK`). The fact that the primary key will be unique will help avoid some of the more obvious problems, but you could still get into problems if you make assumptions about the value you're about to insert *before* you've fully inserted it, or if you don't explicitly *expect* the `insert` to fail.

Answer (score 1):

IDENTITY columns are not depending on other columns. Also, You are trying to derive ServiceID column from the incoming values of SharedKey, SiteId and not from the existing values of the table.

You have few options:

- you need to define an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger to handle this scenario. You need to see whether incoming values of SharedKey, SiteId are already present. If so, use the existing ServiceId. Otherwise, generate new one.
- You need to have this logic as part of insert stored procedure. You need to see the whether incoming parameters: Sharedkey, SiteId are already present. If so use the existing ServiceId. otherwise, generate new one and insert into the table.

**CAVEAT:**

- Going for triggers will make the transaction longer and it will affect concurrency and similarly, checking for existing values in the table and coming up with new ServiceId will make the transaction longer.
- Going for stored procedures also, you need to take care of concurrency aspects(ISOLATION LEVELS) so that your generated serviceID is not creating Primary Key conflict. this kind of ISOLATION LEVEL setting will also affect concurrency.

IMHO, suggesting you below design changes:

- Not to go for this kind of deriving of columns. The composite key constituents have to be independent of each other.
- You can consider creating surrogate key, and have these columns as foreign keys from respective tables. Narrow clustered keys will give good performance, over composite keys.
- Revisit normalization and create separate independent tables and create bridge table to handle this kind of many-many relationship

Comment: even with a stored procedure, you'd need to be aware of the concurrency aspects - i.e. you'd need to anticipate the insert to fail; personally, I'd usually go with surrogate keys here